# Explorer opens new folders in old window

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

Let's say I have two folders on the desktop: Computer and Folder1. If I double click Computer, the Computer folder is opened in an Explorer window. If I then double click Folder1, the Explorer window then navigates to Folder1, instead of opening a new Explorer window. I'd much rather have two Explorer windows at that point.

In folder options, I've set Browse Folders to "Open each folder in its own window" and [under the view tab] checked the box for "Launch folder windows in a separate process". But I'm still getting new folders opened in the same Explorer window.

I'm pretty sure that Windows wasn't doing this originally, but I can't think of what I might have changed. I certainly haven't been editing the registry or anything, although I'm aware that an update may have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this problem was caused by the QtTabBar program, which I use to add tabbed browsing to Explorer. I've had this installed for a while, and haven't changed the settings recently, so I still don't know why this problem came about.

The answer was to disable the "QT Management Toolbar" using the Tools menu in Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

I have found this one (how to change the setting over registry): http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/14562-open-each-folder-same-own-separate-new-window.html

In Registry Editor, navigate to

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CabinetState
```

Using your right arrow key, move the cursor over to the right of the 5th "Value data" (0A), press the Backspace key, type in 2A, and click on OK. (see screenshots below)

[image]

Close regedit.

Comment: I gave this a go, but it unfortunately didn't solve my problem. Thanks for the detailed answer, though!